# Extract numeric value in 1 column and add it in new index under parsed index

Tags: python, dataframe, split, extract, numeric

Many thanks for your helping,
I have big problem that I have data frame like below:

```
Name | Book | Location 
A    | Mobile| Hai Long St. 123
B    | Sim   | Aha 123/456,78;9
```

I would like to separate like below:

```
Name | Book | Location 
A    | Mobile| 123
B    | Sim   | 123
B    | Sim   | 456
B    | Sim   | 78
B    | Sim   | 9
```

How can I do that in python, I don't have any idea for this one. Thank you for you support.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `extractall` to find all numeric values in `Location`:

```
>>> df.Location.str.extractall('(\d+)')
           0
  match     
0 0      123
1 0      123
  1      456
  2       78
  3        9
```

Then, you can join that back into your original dataframe, using the first level of the index of the `extractall` output above. The following is code to get your exact desired output:

```
new_df = (df.drop('Location', axis=1)
          .join(df.Location.str.extractall('(\d+)')
                .reset_index(level=1,drop=True))
          .rename(columns={0:'Location'}))

>>> new_df
  Name    Book Location
0    A  Mobile      123
1    B     Sim      123
1    B     Sim      456
1    B     Sim       78
1    B     Sim        9
```